# Insert range of cells at the beginning of an existing excel worksheet?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have a worksheet that has 5 rows and 3 columns.  I make a copy of this sheet:

```
activeSheet.Copy(Type.Missing, activeSheet);

var outputSheetIndex = activeSheet.Index + 1;

var outputSheet = (Worksheet)application.Sheets[outputSheetIndex];
```

The above copies the sheet into another sheet.  I now want to insert another range into the outputSheet and shift the outputSheet columns to the right.

I am not sure on which range object to apply the `Insert` method on.

I tried creating a new range to insert in the beginning, but this doesn't work:

```
 var startCell = outputSheet.Cells[1, 1];
                    var endCell = outputSheet.Cells[output.Count(),
                        properties.Length + 1];

              var writeRange = outputSheet.Range[startCell, endCell];

writeRange.Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight);
```

When I insert writeRange, I want the existing range of data to be shifted to the right.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is insert a blank column on your new (copied worksheet), I think this would work:

```
outputSheet.Range["A:A"].Insert(
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight,
    Type.Missing);
```

If you want the column somewhere else, you would change "A:A" to your desired range.